# Making a new Primary Key also have constraints

Tags: sql, constraints, primary-key, sql-server-2014

I'm fairly new to SQL Server and am running into what seems like a basic problem.

Essentially my table `COPY_TYPE` has a primary key `C_NAME` and a constraint on `C_NAME`: `VT, VCD, DVD`.

How would I go about having that written out? My bad attempt is what follows:

```
create table COPY_TYPE 
(
     C_NAME char(5) primary key, 
          constraint PK_C_NAME check ( 'VT', 'VCD', 'DVD')
);
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't yet know how to start thinking in this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close - I tend to like to *explicitly name* my constraint, so I'd write it out like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.COPY_TYPE 
(
     C_NAME char(5) NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT PK_Copy_Type PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
         CONSTRAINT CHK_C_NAME CHECK (C_NAME IN ('VT', 'VCD', 'DVD')),
     ... (other columns to follow) ....
);
```

Comment: Awesome, I believe this is what I was looking for! A few minor tweaks, such as the naming of Pk_Copy_type but that's just semantics.
Now I just need to figure out if it's okay to have identical attributes in different tables that are part of multiple primary keys. I suppose that's for another thread though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you to follow:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id, LastName)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table COPY_TYPE (C_NAME char(5) primary key, constraint PK_C_NAME     
check ( C_NAME = 'VT' or C_NAME = 'VCD' or C_NAME = 'DVD'));
```